# Maximum principle for linear elliptic operators of arbitrary order

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

What is known about maximum principles for strongly elliptic linear differential operators of even order (possibly higher than $2$)? By such an operator, I mean a linear differential operator with bounded coefficients whose principal symbol is positive (actually, maybe multiplied by some power of $-1$) and uniformly bounded away from $0$ in space.

I suspect that the maximum principle still holds in an analogous manner, but I've had trouble finding a reference that deals with the theory of elliptic operators in this general manner. Does anybody know where to find such a reference?

Comment: No, [it fails miserably](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/863374/).

Comment: Your first example shows why the naive maximum principle doesn't work on higher-order operators, but my natural guess would be that one needs derivative information up to orders $m-2$, if $m$ is the order of the differential operator. Your example from Hadamard is interesting, however.

Comment: For biharmonic operator you can get something by assuming $u\le 0$ and $-\Delta u\le 0$ on the boundary. Indeed, since $\Delta u$ is harmonic, we have $-\Delta u\le 0$ in the domain, which implies $u\le 0$ in the domain. This is sort of trivial, though. There is sizable  literature on other kinds of maximum principle for biharmonic functions, e.g. [this paper](https://eudml.org/doc/140309). They are M.P. in spirit more than in form.